# Search specific git commit by commit message and exlude branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit, git-show

I am currently working on a program to filter slow db queries that are stored in a database on the command line.

I would like to search all the commits in all the branches except the one specified and return  all the commits that match.

My filter conditions are stored in a database (which is provided for me).

Example:

I have the following entry in the database:

```
ID key       Query
1  ABCDEF    select * from example
2  0ABCDE    select * from another_example
3  1ABCDE    select * from you_get_the_picture
```

I am now interested in the queries that haven't been fixed in the code yet. So I need to search through the branches with the **key** as a search filter.

If the key is found in a commit, skip and look up the next. If no match is found, print it to stdout. All the code works fine but I'm having trouble finding the correct git command.

I have the following:

```
git grep 'ABCDEF' $(git rev-list ^origin/master) | xargs git show -s --format=%N%s
```

Which should return all commits containing "ABCDEF" in the commit message in all the branches except origin/master.

However, the git command doesn't return anything which is not possible since I know that these commits are there.

Is my git command not correct? Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Have you verified that git grep 'ABCDEF' $(git rev-list ^origin/master) gives you the expected output?

Comment: I have checked for git grep 'ABCDEF' $(git rev-list --all) and the results are okay. I'm checking now but it'll take a while...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *not* what you want:

```
$ git rev-list ^origin/master
$
```

You asked `git rev-list` to exclude all revs reachable from `origin/master`, and to include nothing, so it produces nothing.

This may be what you meant:

```
$ git rev-list --branches ^origin/master
c2eb39026567499ba9fe0c679766c370462ae26f
```

Or you might want `--tags` and/or `--remotes` as well or instead; or even `--all` although that includes references like `refs/stash`.

Of course, that goes inside the `git grep` commit arguments as you've shown in your example code; it should work from there—except that `git grep` produces the matching lines, not commit IDs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, how do I filter for the commit message then? 
git rev-list --branches ^origin/master | grep filter

only filter the commit Id

Comment: You probably don't want `git grep`, but rather `git log` with `-S` or -`G`.  See the [`git log` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have now (May 2021, seven years later) a much more precise filtering mechanism with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021): "[`git rev-list`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8585d6c04aa903526b4b3554e90d6381ec62390a/Documentation/git-rev-list.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list))</sup> learns the `--filter=object:type=<type>` option, which can be used to exclude objects of the given kind from the packfile generated by pack-objects.

See [commit 9cf68b2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9cf68b27d50c29a0370bd61581d350b0b0a18e85), [commit 169a15e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/169a15ebd66dd23bf8c379ad33bced1578c848ef), [commit 7ab6aaf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ab6aafa582b9c537885d4a6ef2c837323c5014d), [commit b0c42a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0c42a53c9d36ea69f4d2650001f05e98eb347cb) (19 Apr 2021), [commit 9a2a4f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a2a4f95448890d138a800c8a55c5d5dcfe16082) (12 Apr 2021), and [commit 628d81b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/628d81be6c007de5aa0fa352b912b89f74a5cfa7), [commit b2025da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2025da38be94568bf046c2b8520fe87bcbb5c3d), [commit a812789](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a812789c264b1cabd8e5a22b410a9004781a81c9) (09 Apr 2021) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8585d6c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8585d6c04aa903526b4b3554e90d6381ec62390a), 07 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`list-objects`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0c42a53c9d36ea69f4d2650001f05e98eb347cb): implement object type filter
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> While it already is possible to filter objects by some criteria in `git-rev-list`, it is not yet possible to filter out only a specific type of objects.
>
> This makes some filters less useful.
>
> The `blob:limit` filter for example filters blobs such that only those which are smaller than the given limit are returned.
> But it is unfit to ask only for these smallish blobs, given that `git-rev-list` will continue to print tags, commits and trees.
>
> Now that we have the infrastructure in place to also filter tags and commits, we can improve this situation by implementing a new filter which selects objects based on their type.
> Above query can thus trivially be implemented with the following command:
>
> ```
> $ git rev-list --objects --filter=object:type=blob \
>     --filter=blob:limit=200
> ```
>
> Furthermore, this filter allows to optimize for certain other cases: if for example only tags or commits have been selected, there is no need to walk down trees.
>
> The new filter is not yet supported in bitmaps.
> This is going to be implemented in a subsequent commit.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b0c42a53c9d36ea69f4d2650001f05e98eb347cb/Documentation/config/uploadpack.txt#L69-L71):

> `blob:limit`, `object:type`, `tree`, `sparse:oid`, or `combine`.
> If using combined filters, both `combine` and all of the nested
> filter kinds must be allowed. Defaults to `uploadpackfilter.allow`.

`rev-list-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b0c42a53c9d36ea69f4d2650001f05e98eb347cb/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L895-L897):

> The form '`--filter=object:type=(tag|commit|tree|blob)`' omits all objects
> which are not of the requested type.

And:

> ### [`rev-list`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9cf68b27d50c29a0370bd61581d350b0b0a18e85): allow filtering of provided items
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> When providing an object filter, it is currently impossible to also filter provided items.
> E.g.
> when executing [`git rev-list`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9cf68b27d50c29a0370bd61581d350b0b0a18e85/Documentation/git-rev-list.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list))</sup> HEAD , the commit this reference points to will be treated as user-provided and is thus excluded from the filtering mechanism.
> This makes it harder than necessary to properly use the new `--filter=object:type` filter given that even if the user wants to only see blobs, he'll still see commits of provided references.
>
> Improve this by introducing a new `--filter-provided-objects` option to the git-rev-parse(1) command.
> If given, then all user-provided references will be subject to filtering.

`rev-list-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9cf68b27d50c29a0370bd61581d350b0b0a18e85/Documentation/rev-list-options.txt#L936-L940):

> ### `--filter-provided-objects`
>
> Filter the list of explicitly provided objects, which would otherwise
> always be printed even if they did not match any of the filters. Only
> useful with `--filter=`.